# Word game solving algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, artificial-intelligence, solver

The game consists of a square board of 3X3 up to 7X7 letters.  The player must find up to 10 given words on the board (hardest case).  The letters must be touching each other (within the 8 surrounding squares). As a word is found, it is removed and gravity causes the upper blocks to fill in the gaps (the letters will never move horizontally).  If you're familiar with the mobile game WordBrain, this mechanic is identical.  The difference is that all the words are provided for you, so the algorithm does not need a dictionary to find real words.  The words can be found in any order, and the game is finished when the board is empty.

**Example (7X7 with 8 words):**

Starting state:

```
C E F S C R E
R A U C G C E
T R N A R R C
E C A R C E E
A E E A E A H
R R C A M E L
I E R A R E R

Find: ARCHER CAMERA CARRIER CEREAL 
      CREATE FURNACE GREECE SCARE
```

Now the player decides to remove the word CARRIER (bolded letters):

[image: Finding CARRIER]

Resulting board state:

```
      S C R E
    F C G C E
    U A R R C
C E N R C E E
R A A A E A H
T R E A M E L
E E C A R E R

Find: ARCHER CAMERA CEREAL 
      CREATE FURNACE GREECE SCARE
```

I'm guaranteed that the starting state is solvable.  Now that CARRIER was removed, I no longer have any guarantees about solvability.

**So that's how the game is played.  From an algorithms standpoint, what is the correct, most efficient way to solve this?**

**EDIT: Made question more succinct at the request of this great SO community.**

Comment: I think this is "too broad". You might consider putting up *real* code on codereview.stackexchange.com instead and ask for a review of that.

Comment: I think this is interesting problem, but sadly getting close votes.

Comment: You do not only have the 8! permutations, but also possibly multiple variants how to remove any given word (e.g. there are many more possibilities to form "carrier" just with the letters in the lower-left corner). What's more, those possibilities are different depending on what words have been removed before, and in which variant, and this will cause different letters to fall close to each other.

Comment: Probably not optimal, but I'd implement a backtracking algorithm, finding and trying all the possibilities to remove _any_ word from the grid and continuing/backtracking until it finds a way to remove them all.

Comment: Do the letters also collapse horizontally if any column is entirely cleared? If not, this may cause real problems (and rule out many possible moves) as this would create disconnected regions of the grid.

Comment: @tobias_k No.  Just vertically.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm interested in your backtracking idea.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean though.

Comment: @NielW Actually, the backtracking is probably the easiest; I'm currently thinking about the best way to get all the possibly ways to select cells for a given word. Do you happen to have parts of the code already, e.g. for that subproblem, that we can use in our solutions?

Comment: Oh I'm already doing that.  It's built into the recursion algorithm by default.  From solution description: "If it dead-ends, it goes back up the stack one level and looks at the next possibility."  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @NielW When you say "unsolveable", do you mean when there are no possible moves left. Or do you mean that we can still remove some words from the board, but ultimately it can't be solved?

Comment: Unsolvable just means that no matter what I do, the board will never reach a solvable state, even if there are currently words left to be found.  Either the board can be cleared, or it can't.  No points for getting close.

Answer (score 2):

I have made many word games so I will comment here about an overall approach and of which I believe is NP so only valid for small board sizes. Since the question is more about finding a Board Clearing solution rather than a finding of possible words, I won't cover the topic of how to solve for all findable words for a given length n as it was previously mentioned and solvable by using Prefix Tries, and very search-able in google. Also, I am assuming columns shift together much like a standard match3 when a column clears.

Almost all game solvers have a similar pattern to their algorithm design. For a match3 game:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15063/ai-for-solving-a-match-3-game
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/575282-solving-bejeweled-type-game/

1. Generate possible moves
2. Sort possible moves by evaluation heuristic
3. Make each move and re-evaluate, 
   note: making a move means adding a node to the tree.
4. Dive in tree
5. If resulting board heuristic < previous, climb tree and prune.
6. Visit next sibling

Thus comes the discussion for your rules.

1. What makes a good cost function?

In this game, the optimal goal is to remove a word such that the resulting grid remains as square as possible. This maximizes each letters potential. Isolated letters, which only have 1 neighbor vastly diminish the possible word list greatly. Thus a good cost, might be the 'squareness' of a board.

2. Sorting possible moves based on an evaluation.

   A starting point here may be just a length search. Try making the longest word first.
3. The art of early out testing

If the puzzle is built with N words of the same length, then an easy early out would be if the possible words list does not contain a word of this length. Starting from the edges of the far left and far right, if one of these columns has a letter with only 1 letter, there are certain bigrams that can be almost immediately returned.

Think of this case:

```
    B I
    A G 
Z X C T Y Y
```

This should be considered a bad board, because no words start with Z X or end in XZ

Comment: I like the idea of trying to find a good heuristic, but I'm not sure squareness applies in this case, because the columns actually do not collapse horizontally.  Blocks can only move vertically.  But this makes me wonder what a good heuristic would be.  I'm not sure I can even come up with one.  Is there a way to score a board such that a higher scoring board indicates higher likelihood of solvability?  I can watch for deadend cases, like you mentioned, but that's a binary outcome.  EIther it deadends (not solvable) or it doesn't (possibly solvable.)

Comment: You may want to do some reading on what quackle does. I used it years ago for a scrabble game and was impressed by how good it is: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jasonkb/quackle/doc/how_quackle_plays_scrabble.html  It is specific to scrabble but the approach is similar, it did beat a world champion